# looping until user enters 'x'

Tags: c

basically my code stops working after my first input where i chose one of the following cases, but it should keep on workin until i choose case x.
can anybody help and tell me where the issue is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
char choice;
int a,b,c,s;
int F;

    printf("Objekttyp wahlen:\n (R) Rechteck\n (E) Ellipse\n (D) Dreieck\n (x) Exit\n");
        choice = getchar();
            while(choice == '\n'){
                choice = getchar();
            }

            switch(choice){
            case 'R':
                printf("Seitenlaengen a,b des Rechtecks: ");
                    scanf("%d%d" &&a, &b);
                        F = a * b;
                            printf("F = %d", F);
                break;


            case 'E':
                printf("Halbachsen der Ellipse: ");
                    scanf("%d%d" &&a, &b);
                        F = 3.14 * a * b;
                            printf("F = %d", F);
                break;
            case 'D':
                printf("Seitenlaengen a,b,c des Dreiecks: ");
                    scanf("%d%d%d" &&a,b,c);

                            printf("F = %d", F);
                break;
            case 'x':
                exit(0);
                break;
            
            default :
                printf("Ungueltige Eingabe!\n\n");
            }while(choice != 'x');

}
```

Comment: Stepping through the code with a debugger will tell you that `switch (...) { } while (...);` does not do what you think.

Comment: Replace &&a with &a in the scanf statement.

Comment: To make Raymond Chen's answer more clear: You have to write
`while (...) { switch (...) { ... } }`

Comment: Why use `exit(0);` and check for `x` in a loop condition? Do one or the other. I'd prefer using the loop condition.

Comment: @Iziminza I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be a `do { ... } while(...);` loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way: If you want to output the German umlauts in the console (for example `"Ungültige Eingabe!\n\n"`), you can write: `printf("Ung\x81 \bltige Eingabe!\n\n");`
The console is using the [codepage 850](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepage_850)...

`printf("Seitenl\x84 \bngen a,b des Rechtecks: ");`

You just have to put a space after \x81 so that the next character is not interpreted with the previos characters. You can undo this extra space with \b.

Comment: Thanks last time i had the issue with a space between this helped :)

Answer (score 2):

use a do-while loop, instead of switch-while because the switch while loop doesn't exist, at least not in c++ or c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
char choice;
int a,b,c,s;
int F;
do{
    printf("Objekttyp wahlen:\n (R) Rechteck\n (E) Ellipse\n (D) Dreieck\n (x) Exit\n");
        choice = getchar();
            while(choice == '\n'){
                choice = getchar();
            }

            switch(choice){
            case 'R':
                printf("Seitenlaengen a,b des Rechtecks: ");
                    scanf("%d%d" &&a, &b);
                        F = a * b;
                            printf("F = %d", F);
                break;


            case 'E':
                printf("Halbachsen der Ellipse: ");
                    scanf("%d%d" &&a, &b);
                        F = 3.14 * a * b;
                            printf("F = %d", F);
                break;
            case 'D':
                printf("Seitenlaengen a,b,c des Dreiecks: ");
                    scanf("%d%d%d" &&a,b,c);

                            printf("F = %d", F);
                break;
            case 'x':
                exit(0);
                break;
            
            default :
                printf("Ungueltige Eingabe!\n\n");
            }
    }while(choice != 'x');

}
```

Comment: thank you , this helped alot and i decided to only use while(choice != 'x') and used goto to always jump to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

**Beautiful code format：**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    char choice;
    int a,b,c,s;
    int F;
    do{
        printf("Objekttyp wahlen:\n (R) Rechteck\n (E) Ellipse\n (D) Dreieck\n (x) Exit\n");
        choice = getchar();
        while(choice == '\n'){
            choice = getchar();
        }

        switch(choice){
            case 'R':
                printf("Seitenlaengen a,b des Rechtecks: ");
                scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
                F = a * b;
                printf("F = %d\n", F);
                break;

            case 'E':
                printf("Halbachsen der Ellipse: ");
                scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
                F = 3.14 * a * b;
                printf("F = %d\n", F);
                break;
            
            case 'D':
                printf("Seitenlaengen a,b,c des Dreiecks: ");
                scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
                printf("F = %d\n", F);
                break;

            case 'x':
                exit(0);
                break;
            
            default :
                printf("Ungueltige Eingabe!\n\n");
        }
    }while(choice != 'x');
}
```

**there is other problem:**
change

```
scanf("%d%d" &&a, &b);
```

to

```
scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
```